# Easier way to do character print with attribute in assembly

Tags: assembly, attributes, character, pixel, tasm

All in all I want to output this picture in assembly but the problem is I don't know how to work on grids and it is very confusing. What I want to ask is:

Are there other/easier ways to do this?

If not, then can you help me understand how to do this like my sample code?

Here's the picture:
[image]

I just started coding it using grids but I imagine it's going to be so tedious and confusing because in this code I'm only trying to print one pixel and it's already showing errors because I'm confused with grids.

```
.model small
.code
org 100h

start:
        mov ah,06h
    mov bh,40h
    mov ch,10
    mov cl,0
    mov dh,5
    mov dl,0
    int 10h

    mov ah,02h
    mov dh,24
    mov dl,0
    mov bh,0    
    int 10h
    int 20h
end start
```

Comment: Why don't you just store your "image" as a 2-dimensional array in your program, and then just print it to the screen line by line?

Comment: Do you have references where I can read up on that subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using VGA text mode anyway, you can store your picture as an array of constants and copy it to the VGA frame buffer http://wiki.osdev.org/Text_UI

Comment: I don't get it, the goal is to print the pixels in cmd tasm.

Comment: I have no knowledge in assembly.

Comment: See, basically your program tries to scroll the text buffer (supposedly clearing it) and then set the cursor position.

Comment: It seems like you intend to output characters ("pixels") then. So, instead of calling BIOS functions, you can write values representing your 'pixels' to the memory addresses of the VGA frame buffer so the video adapter will find them there and draw 'pixels'